# Ruby On Rails :Upgrading to 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What kind of development environment needed to upgrade a webapplication developed in older version of Ruby deployed in Linux to latest version 2.3.11.

I am a windows .net developer and looking some help in terms of understanding the development environment. I know little bit about pearl and ruby.

Do i need to install Linux or mac. Or can i develop/test in windows and once ready deploy to linux?

I have a linux server, can i use that as development server and do the Remote desktop from my windows to that for development work? What IDE i should get install in that linux server.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Choice of development environments.**

While you could develop your app in Windows and then deploy to a Linux server, that's almost never the right choice. Since you already have access to a Linux machine, Windows is certainly not the right choice in this case.

As for an IDE on the Linux box, you don't need one. Do yourself a huge favor, choose to learn either vim or emacs, suffer with the mental phase shifting for a week, and do all of your work via ssh to the Linux box. You will be slower in the short term, but the long term payoff is huge.

I would be willing to bet that you'll lose less time while learning one of those text editors than you will lose by dinking around with Ruby + Windows and then trying to sync that with your Linux environment.

**Upgrading Rails to 2.3.11**

This begs the obvious question. What version does the app use now? 2.3.* to 2.3.11 is a piece of cake. If you're talking about more ancient code, then plan on some pain and refactoring. If the code is really old, then seriously consider going straight to Rails 3.